# How initialize double pointer struct array in C++?

Tags: c++

I have a structure like below,

```
struct myStruct
{
CString a;
int b;
CString c;
int d;
}
```

The char** array can be initialized as below,

```
char **choices = (char *[]){ "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
```

Similarly how to initialize double pointer structure array. My requirement is I should not do dynamic memory allocations using new or malloc.

I need below kind of initialization.

```
myStruct** arr ={
....
....
....
....
};
```

Comment: You need to turn up your warnings.  You compiler should be screaming at you about how `choices` is initialized as you are violating const-correctness and lifetime rules: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/66cd453d5d595950

Comment: Why do you need a pointer to a pointer initialization? To me it looks like you just want a simple array of `myStruct`

Comment: I agree on what@UnholySheep said. Why don't you use `std::vector<myStruct>`?

Comment: @schorsch312 well, they did say specifically that their requirement is to not do dynamic memory allocations.

Comment: @user2079303 I missed that. Then I suggest to use `std::array` of myStruct ans the fixed Site.

Comment: @NathanOliver, from this link only I took the code http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.1.1/gcc/Compound-Literals.html                                                                                           char **choices = (char *[]){ "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };

Comment: @User890 That code is for C.  C is not the same as C++ and this is one of those places where valid C is not valid C++.

Answer (score 4):

First create a few `myStruct` objects:

```
myStruct ms1;
myStruct ms2;
```

Then create an array of pointers to `myStruct`:

```
myStruct* pointerArray[] = {&ms1, &ms2};
```

Finally, you can take the pointer to first element of that array. This is your "double pointer struct array" without dynamic allocation.

```
myStruct** arr = pointerArray;
```

---

> ```
> char **choices = (char *[]){ "New Game", "Continue Game", "Exit" };
> ```

This line has a few problems.

Firstly, the initialization syntax that you use is ill-formed in C++. Compound literals are a C99 feature and are not in the C++ language.

Secondly, you convert string literals to *non-const `char*`*. String literals are const in C++, and such conversion from const to non-const is ill-formed (since C++11; prior to that the conversion was deprecated).